How can I set multiple print area with openpyxl
I have an Excel file which includes one Excel sheet. in the sheet, there are multiple different sections that I want to add to the print area. But in openpyxl I find that I can set only one print area. Are there any options for multiple printing in openpyxl or other libraries in the existing worksheet?

Should be able to add the ranges together in the one command
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

printArea = ["'Sheet1'!$A$1:$Q$34","'Sheet1'!$A$40:$Q$75"]
print(f"PA1: {printArea[0]}\nPA2: {printArea[1]}")
sheet.print_area = f'{printArea[0]},{printArea[1]}'

wb.save('foo.xlsx')


If you want to try another library like Xlwings;
import xlwings as xw

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book('foo.xlsx')
    ws = wb.sheets('Sheet1')

    ws.page_setup.print_area = "A1:F10, A15:E19, A21:B22"

    ### Or using the api and full co-ords if preferred.
    # ws.api.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$F$10,$A$15:$E$19,$A$21:$B$22"

    wb.save('foo.xlsx')


didn't work in this approach

Works for me. I noticed the second comma was a period in the example above so make sure each range is separated by a comma (updated the code sample). If that is OK, what version of Openpyxl do you have? must be later than around 2.4, earlier than that and the function did not exist (better if you have the latest release 3.1.2 ). If the version is up to date how are you implementing and determining it doesn't work?

I got the openpyxl latest version and i do this
sheet.print_area = f'{printArea[0]},{printArea[1]}'
print(sheet.print_area)
the output in console is  'Sheet1'!$A$1:$Q$34,'Sheet1'!$A$40:$Q$75
but in excel this area in print are not selected

Not sure why you specify the Sheet name in the range. The Print Area is applied to the Sheet not the workbook so the Sheet name is not necessary. However I have updated the code example to use the Print Area values you have provided. The two Print Areas are still set correctly. If the name of the worksheet you are applying the Print Areas to was not 'Sheet1' those Print Areas would still be set on that Sheet.

It actually works. The issue was scaling. the print you area you provide work correctly, Thanks.

You can give your first answer. I hope it will help many people
